# Using "from" in Python (directory name begins with a number, invalid identifier)

Tags: python, python-import

I am just trying to import from different directories.
This works:

```
if (ssize == 32):
    from Python_32bit import mycoolmodule
else:
    from Python_64bit import mycoolmodule
```

But this does not:

```
if (ssize == 32):
    from 32bit_Python import mycoolmodule
else:
    from 64bit_Python import mycoolmodule
```

Comment: `import` doesn't import from "directories", it imports [from] *modules*. Module names must be valid module names. Valid names may not start with numbers.

Comment: I didn't know that:  Module names must not start with numbers.

Comment: No "names" in Python may start with a number, including variables, classes, functions etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valid module name have to be correct [identifier](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).

Identifiers follow lexical notation defined as:

```
identifier ::=  (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*
letter     ::=  lowercase | uppercase
lowercase  ::=  "a"..."z"
uppercase  ::=  "A"..."Z"
digit      ::=  "0"..."9"
```

- `Python_32bit` is a valid identifier.
- `32bit_Python` is not (it starts with a number, while identifiers have to start with `(letter|"_")`).